# How to perform cell by cell comparison using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Supposing I have a **df** like the following,

```
col1   | type   | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 |.... | date_n
ab     |   A    |  -10   |        |  -10
ab     |   B    |  100   |   99   |  -12
cd     |   A    |   0    |  -25   |   6
cd     |   B    |  -1    |   8    |  -34
ab     |   A    |   98   |  -9    |   0
ab     |   B    |  -7    |  -2    |   0
```

First step is to remove all positive numbers including 0

Now the **df** should look like,

```
col1   | type   | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 | .... | date_n
ab     |   A    |  -10   |        |  -10   |
ab     |   B    |        |        |  -12   |
cd     |   A    |        |  -25   |        |
cd     |   B    |  -1    |        |  -34   |
ab     |   A    |        |  -9    |        |
ab     |   B    |  -7    |  -2    |        |
```

Second step is to compare the numbers for each 'date' col as per 'type' A and B,

- If the 'type' A row has a negative number and 'type' B is blank, then remove the negative number, of 'date' col, of 'type' A
- If the 'type' B row has a negative number and 'type' A is blank, then do nothing
- If both types are blank do nothing

After this step, the **df** should look like this,

```
col1   | type   | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 | .... | date_n
ab     |   A    |        |        |  -10   |
ab     |   B    |        |        |  -12   |
cd     |   A    |        |        |        |
cd     |   B    |  -1    |        |  -34   |
ab     |   A    |        |  -9    |        |
ab     |   B    |  -7    |  -2    |        |
```

Final step,

- If both types are negative for the current, for each set of col1 (ab,cd,ab), check the left-hand-side value of same Ath and Bth of the same row,

  ```
  1) If both types A and B values are blank, then remove the remove the negative number of current row 'type' A and keep the -ve number of 'type' B

  2) If either of the types are blank, then remove the negative of the current row 'type' B and keep the -ve number of 'type' A
  ```

Finally, the **final_df** should look like this,

```
col1   | type   | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 | .... | date_n
ab     |   A    |        |        |        |
ab     |   B    |        |        |  -12   |
cd     |   A    |        |        |        |
cd     |   B    |  -1    |        |  -34   |
ab     |   A    |        |  -9    |        |
ab     |   B    |  -7    |        |        |
```

For the final step, the comparison should start from the 'date_2'.

What would be the best way to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I cannot use the column headers (the date ones) to manipulate data because they will keep changing.

Test Data:

```
{'column1': ['CT', 'CT', 'NBB', 'NBB', 'CT', 'CT', 'NBB', 'NBB', 'HHH', 'HHH', 'TP1', 'TP1', 'TPR', 'TPR', 'PP1', 'PP1', 'PP1', 'PP1'], 'column2': ['POUPOU', 'POUPOU', 'PRPRP', 'PRPRP', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STEVT', 'STEVT', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SHW', 'SHW', 'JV', 'JV'], 'column3': ['V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV'], 'column4': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'column5': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'column6': ['BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'VVV', 'VVV', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CHCH', 'CHCH'], 'column7': ['Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21'], 'Feb-21': [11655, 0, 0, 0, 121117, 0, 14948, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1838, 0, 0, 0], 'Mar-21': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -16474.0, -16474.0, 7000.0, 7000.0, -19946.0, -19946.0, 16084.44444444444, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'Apr-21': [104815.0, 104815.0, 17949.0, 17949.0, 96132.0, 96132.0, 0.0, 0.0, -17001.0, -33475.0, -878.0, 6122.0, 8398.0, -11548.0, -5297.073170731703, -5297.073170731703, -282.0, -282.0], 'May-21': [78260.0, 183075.0, 42557.0, 60506.0, -15265.0, 80867.0, -18.0, -18.0, 21084.0, -12391.0, -1831.0, 4291.0, 2862.0, -8686.0, 5261.25, -35.8231707317027, -369.0, -651.0], 'Jun-21': [-52480.0, 130595.0, -13258.0, 47248.0, -35577.0, 45290.0, 2434.0, 2416.0, 31147.0, 18756.0, -4310.0, -19.0, -4750.0, -13436.0, -92.0, -127.8231707317027, -280.0, -931.0], 'Jul-21': [-174544.0, -43949.0, -38127.0, 9121.0, -124986.0, -79696.0, -9707.0, -7291.0, 13577.0, 32333.0, 0.0, -19.0, -15746.0, -29182.0, 93.0, -34.8231707317027, -319.0, -1250.0], 'Aug-21': [35498.0, -8451.0, -37094.0, -27973.0, 79021.0, -675.0, -1423.0, -8714.0, 32168.0, 64501.0, 0.0, -19.0, 18702.0, -10480.0, 4347.634146341465, 4312.810975609762, -341.0, -1591.0], 'Sep-21': [44195.0, 35744.0, 2039.0, -25934.0, 70959.0, 70284.0, 2816.0, -5898.0, 38359.0, 102860.0, 0.0, -19.0, 18119.0, 7639.0, 5302.222222222219, 9615.033197831981, 0.0, -1591.0], 'Oct-21': [-13163.0, 22581.0, -4773.0, -30707.0, 205080.0, 275364.0, -709.0, -6607.0, -1397.0, 101463.0, 0.0, -19.0, 0.0, 7639.0, -34.0, 9581.033197831981, 0.0, -1591.0]}
```

Expected output:

```
{'column1': ['CT', 'CT', 'NBB', 'NBB', 'CT', 'CT', 'NBB', 'NBB', 'HHH', 'HHH', 'TP1', 'TP1', 'TPR', 'TPR', 'PP1', 'PP1', 'PP1', 'PP1'], 'column2': ['POUPOU', 'POUPOU', 'PRPRP', 'PRPRP', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STEVT', 'STEVT', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SHW', 'SHW', 'JV', 'JV'], 'column3': ['V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV'], 'column4': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'column5': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'column6': ['BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'VVV', 'VVV', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CHCH', 'CHCH'], 'column7': ['Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21'], 'Feb-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Mar-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -16474.0, nan, nan, nan, -19946.0, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Apr-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -17001.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, -11548.0, nan, -5297.073170731703, nan, -282.0], 'May-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -18.0, nan, -12391.0, nan, nan, nan, -8686.0, nan, -35.8231707317027, -369.0, nan], 'Jun-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, -4750.0, nan, -92.0, nan, -280.0, nan], 'Jul-21': [nan, -43949.0, nan, nan, nan, -79696.0, nan, -7291.0, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, -15746.0, nan, nan, -34.8231707317027, -319.0, nan], 'Aug-21': [nan, -8451.0, nan, -27973.0, nan, -675.0, -1423.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, nan, -10480.0, nan, nan, -341.0, nan], 'Sep-21': [nan, nan, nan, -25934.0, nan, nan, nan, -5898.0, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -1591.0], 'Oct-21': [nan, nan, -4773.0, nan, nan, nan, -709.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -1591.0]}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Is possible explain more final step? why for `ef` is removed `-2` annd for `ab` `-10` ?

Comment: What does mean `check the left-hand-side of the same row` ?

Comment: for final step, we start with col date_2 and compare the values with that of date_1. For ef we remove -2 because to the left, that is, values in col date_1 are negative and according to the condition mentioned, the value of the corresponding type B is removed and type A is kept. Hope this helps!

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidHaris I am actually struggling with the Final Step. I thought it would be better to explain the entire problem to see if someone has a better/efficient way to approach this problem :)

Comment: So it means `date_2, date_3`... are selected `A` or `B` by check `date_1` ? So if exist values there (in date_1) like `ef` then is removed `B` else removed `A` ?

Comment: no..date_2 will be compared with date_1, date_3 will be compared with date_2 and so on. Please let me know if anything else is unclear.

Comment: Ok, so -10 removed, because no values in `date_2` for `ab`'?

Comment: that is correct according to second point under final step..

Comment: can you provide more details about your last steps? I have created a rough solution up till 2nd step but further details are little confusing.

Comment: for the final step, if we take date_2 col, you will see that the values for ef's A and B (date_1) are both negative, and according to the mentioned condition, type B will be removed, that is, -2. Now, if we consider date_3 col, since the cells of date_2 for ab is blank, then -10 will be removed according to the mentioned condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

```
rem_cols = [ 'col2', 'subtype',  'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
df['g'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'type'] ).cumcount()

df1 = df.drop(rem_cols, axis=1)

df1 = df1.set_index(['col1','g', 'type'])


df1.columns = pd.to_datetime(df1.columns)

first_date = df1.columns[0]
df1 = df1.unstack(-1)

# print (df1.stack(dropna=False).reset_index())

df1 = df1.mask(df1.ge(0))

m1 = (df1.xs('A', level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).notna() & 
      df1.xs('B', level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).rename(columns={'B':'A'}, level=1).isna())
m2 = (df1.xs('B', level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).notna() &
      df1.xs('A', level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).rename(columns={'A':'B'}, level=1).isna())

m = m1.join(m2)

df1 = df1.mask(m)
# print (df1)

df2 = df1.groupby(level=1, axis=1).shift(1, axis=1)
# print (df2)

mask1 = df1.notna() & df2.isna() & (df1.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'A')[ None, :]
#avoid change values for date_1
mask1[first_date] = False

mask2 = df1.notna() & df2.notna() & (df1.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'B')[ None, :]

df1 = df1.mask(mask1).mask(mask2).stack(dropna=False)
# print (df1)

df = df[rem_cols + ['col1','g', 'type']].join(df1, on=['col1','g', 'type'])
print (df)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, looks clean! Is there a way to make it generic though? Cause the name of the date_n cols keep changing according to the month...so `mask1['date_1'] = False` won't work. But all these date_n cols will have values as numbers or NaN always. I wonder if there is a way to make it generic.

Comment: there is one complication that I just noticed..How to deal with the problem when there is a possibility that there'll be a duplication of col1? And we cannot combine them as well..

Comment: where would the change be made?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Please give me some time, I change answer for correct working

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Can you check my edited answer?

Comment: yes, i'll check but it seems like for some reason the code doesn't work for the data I have?! I am confused. Maybe I can add a test data for your reference. I am getting all NaN values.

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Hmm, not idea. For me working well :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228293/discussion-between-royalewithcheese-and-jezrael).

Comment: Hi, I have updated my Test data to include the columns I was mentioning, could you please have a look as to what needs to be changed from your current solution?

I tried running the Test data with your solution and found that there is some data missing mostly the duplicated values across given col1 and type. Could you please help me in running a last test on the basis of the provided data? Instead of deleting the duplicated values I want to be able to retain it.

Comment: any suggestions? I have even added the output I am getting

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Is possible add correct output?

Comment: sure, please give me sometime

Comment: I have edited and added the correct output in the question itself. Did you happen to have a look at it?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Not understand, there are some new columns, is necessary remove them? What means type, subtype?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - also what was changed in my solution? With my solution is impossible get `wrong ouput`.

Comment: cannot remove the new columns, that was actually the original df but thought of removing the unnecessary because I thought I could merge the df's later on the basis of col1 and type but there seems to multiple matches for these two rows so I added all cols in the question now.

Comment: regarding your solution, I changed `first_date = df1.columns[3]` and `dfn = df.select_dtypes('number')
df[dfn.columns] = dfn.mask(dfn.ge(0))`

Comment: subtype is like a codeword for type column @jezrael

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Hmmm, problem is your change completely broke my solution :(

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Solution need only `col1, type` and datetimes columns. If add new columns it broke it.

Comment: so there is no way to apply some changes to your solution or could you take this as my new question?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Yes, remove unnecessary columns, apply my solution and merge unnecessary columns should working.

Comment: yeah i tried merging it back but end up with duplicated rows..could u give it a shot?

Comment: and it doesn't actually break your solution completely just some data for the unnecessary columns go missing

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Ok, problem is if use `unstack` then get different DataFrame if use 2 columns col1, type and if use N columns. So it is reason for different output.

Comment: is it possible for you to approach this problem in a new way then? I can edit the entire question if required.

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Not easy working with data, but I can try it.

Comment: maybe try merging first?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - there are `type   col2  col3` columns which are not use in my solution?

Comment: you mean `subtype`?

Comment: `subtype is like a codeword for type column` ? It means in my solution is use `col1, type` or `col1, subtype` ?

Comment: for your solution - col1, type

Comment: i just changed the two lines code from your solution which I have mentioned before apart from that have kept everything else the same..

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Just thinking about not merge alternative, working on it. Btw, there is alot columns without `type, col1` and datetimes columns?

Comment: there is but the cols that I have added should cover the test cases

Comment: let me edit and put the test data with all cols, i think it will be better

Comment: I have added the data that I am working with for your reference.

Comment: also a heads up, the 'datetime' like column names have to be generic because they keep changing..

Comment: @royalewithcheese - sure ;)

Comment: any progress @jezrael? I think merging won't work because there are duplicate values for a given `col1` and `type`

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Still it not reduced rows after first `.unstack()`, investigate why.

Comment: Found problem, is necessary drop columns.

Comment: otherwise not possible? and could you explain the problem?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Is possible go to chat?

Comment: hello, it seems like there is some discrepancy in the final output. Could you please please help me out?   I tried your making minor tweaks in your solution, but I am really stuck.
I shall upload the test data and the expected output data as well by tomorrow.

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Can you create new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66422275/how-to-manipulate-data-cell-by-cell-in-pandas-df

Comment: were you able to see df2? I have added a link to my question above

Comment: @royalewithcheese - I think it is really complicated, in this answer I use 3 hours, really not easy. So I suggest break new questions to more parts, simpliest like possible.

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Now I was lost in new question, unfortunately.

Comment: It is the same question, just explained with examples to give a better understanding. You can try the same code for df1 and check the result for df2 as there are some values are either missing or have not been included.

Comment: @royalewithcheese - hmmm, I think missing expected otput.

Comment: I think the problem occurred in Step 4. Could you please check that part only, the rest should be same.

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Also picture are super, but for more complicated data is much better add part from inout data - not only negative, but what is negative.

Comment: they're negative numbers.

Comment: you cannot see df2? I added a link in the question..Please check

Comment: @royalewithcheese - I miss it.

Comment: @royalewithcheese - So what row and column is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229343/discussion-between-jezrael-and-royalewithcheese).

Answer (score 2):

An alternate using `numpy` and building truth table.  Logic for step 3 is a bit write once, read never.  Added another test case *gh*

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""col1   | type   | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 
ab     |   A    |  -10   |    --    |  -10
ab     |   B    |  100   |   99   |  -12
cd     |   A    |   0    |  -25   |   6
cd     |   B    |  -1    |   8    |  -34
ef     |   A    |  -98   |  -9    |   0
ef     |   B    |  -7    |  -2    |   0
gh     |   A    |  -22   |  0    |   -3
gh     |   B    |  -75   |  0    |   -1

"""), sep="\s+\|\s+", engine="python").replace("--", "", regex=True)

# reshape dataframe so it's in better structure for steps
dfs = df.set_index(["col1","type"]).unstack(1)

# step 1,  identify all -ve values
a = dfs.replace("", 0).astype(int).lt(0).values
# step 2, keep where negative for type A & B,  note 2 relates to len(["A","B"])
ap = a.reshape((a.shape[0]*a.shape[1])//2, 2).all(axis=1)
a = np.repeat(ap,2).reshape(a.shape)

# step 3
# B are odd columns...
bcol = [bcol for bcol in range(a.shape[1]) if bcol%2==1]
# if A&B are both -ve for first date,  remove B value for other dates
# logic: a. A&B both -ve: a[:,[0,1]].all(axis=1),2)
#        b. logical and(not(A&B -ve), (B -ve))
a[:,bcol[1:]] = a[:,bcol[1:]]&np.repeat(~a[:,[0,1]].all(axis=1),2).reshape(len(dfs),2)

# rebuild df with truth array built for step 1&2&3
dfs.loc[:] = np.where(a, dfs, "")

# back to original shape...
df = dfs.stack().reset_index()
```

### output

```
  col1 type date_1 date_2 date_3
0   ab    A                  -10
1   ab    B                  -12
2   cd    A                     
3   cd    B                     
4   ef    A    -98     -9       
5   ef    B     -7              
6   gh    A    -22            -3
7   gh    B    -75
```

#### blank and negative A

- replace step 1 with a more sophisticated binary logic

```
# col A, blanks & negative
a = (((dfs.columns.get_level_values(1)=="A") 
 & dfs.replace("",0).astype(int).le(0)) |
# col B, only negative
((dfs.columns.get_level_values(1)=="B") 
 & dfs.replace("",0).astype(int).lt(0))).values
```

Comment: I have given extensive explanation of step 3, you may have a look, if anything is unclear please let me know. Also, I made an edit to the question.

Comment: updated - logic for step 3 works but is not very readable...

Comment: what would I have to change if for step 2, I want to keep the negative number for B should there be a situation where B has a negative number but A is blank?

Comment: I've updated the answer - it's a modification of step 1

Comment: Thanks for the update. When I run your code using the test data (which I have added in the question), I get the following error at the last step `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,8) (12,2)`

Comment: Could you please try to run your algo using my test data perhaps? I have also added the expected output.