# How to manipulate data cell by cell in pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let the sample df (df1) be,

[image: sample data]

We can achieve df2 or final data-frame by manipulating the data of df1 in the following manner,

**Step 1**: Remove all positive numbers including zeros

After Step 1 the sample data should look like,

[image: sample data after Step1]

**Step 2**: If `column4` A row is a negative number and `column4` B is blank, then remove the -ve number of `column4` A row

**Step 3**: If `column4` A row is blank and `column4` B is a negative number, then keep the -ve number of `column4` B row

[image: sample data after step2 and 3]

After Steps 1,2 and 3 are done,

**Step 4**: If both A and B of `column4` are negative then,

For each A and B row of `column4`, check the left-side (LHS) value (for a given month) of the same A and B row of `column4`

**Step 4.1**: If either of the LHS values of A or B is a -ve number, then delete the current row value of B `column4` and keep the current row value of A `column4`

After Step 4.1, the sample data should look like this,

[image: sample data after step 4.1]

**Step 4.2**:

If the LHS value of A and B `column4` is blank, then keep the current row value of B `column4` and delete the current row value of A `column4`

Sample data after Step 4.2 should look like,

[image: sample data after step4.2]

Since we see two negative numbers still, we perform Step 4.1 again and then the final data-frame or df2 will look like,

[image: sample data after Step4.1]

How may I achieve the above using pandas? I was able to achieve till Step 1 but have no idea as to how to proceed further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the approach that I took,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('df1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_pickle('./df1.pkl')
unpickled_df = pd.read_pickle('./df1.pkl')
rem_cols = ['column2', 'column3', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7']
unpickled_df['g'] = unpickled_df.groupby(['column1', 'column4'] ).cumcount()
df1 = unpickled_df.drop(rem_cols, axis=1)
df1 = df1.set_index(['column1','g', 'column4'])
df1.columns = pd.to_datetime(df1.columns, format='%b-%y').strftime('%b-%y')
first_date = df1.columns[0]
df1 = df1.unstack(-1)
df1 = df1.mask(df1.ge(0))
m1 = (df1.xs('A', level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).notna() & 
      df1.xs('B', level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).rename(columns={'B':'A'}, level=1).isna())
m2 = (df1.xs('B', level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).notna() &
      df1.xs('A', level=1, axis=1, drop_level=False).rename(columns={'A':'B'}, level=1).isna())

m = m1.join(m2)
df1 = df1.mask(m)
df2 = df1.groupby(level=1, axis=1).shift(1, axis=1)
mask1 = df1.notna() & df2.isna() & (df1.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'A')[ None, :]
mask1[first_date] = False
mask2 = df1.notna() & df2.notna() & (df1.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'B')[ None, :]
df1 = df1.mask(mask1).mask(mask2).stack(dropna=False)
unpickled_df = unpickled_df[rem_cols + ['column1','g', 'column4']].join(df1, on=['column1','g', 'column4'])
#print(unpickled_df)
```

Small Test data:
df1,

```
{'column1': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'CDF', 'CDF'], 'column4': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Feb-21': [0, 10, 0, 0], 'Mar-21': [0, 0, 70, 70], 'Apr-21': [-10, -10, -8, 60], 'May-21': [-30, -60, -10, 40], 'Jun-21': [-20, 9, -40, -20], 'Jul-21': [30, -10, 0, -20], 'Aug-21': [-30, -20, 0, -20], 'Sep-21': [0, -15, 0, -20], 'Oct-21': [0, -15, 0, -20]}
```

df2 (expected output),

```
{'column1': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'CDF', 'CDF'], 'column4': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Feb-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Mar-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Apr-21': [nan, -10.0, nan, nan], 'May-21': [-30.0, nan, nan, nan], 'Jun-21': [nan, nan, nan, -20.0], 'Jul-21': [nan, -10.0, nan, -20.0], 'Aug-21': [-30.0, nan, nan, -20.0], 'Sep-21': [nan, -15.0, nan, -20.0], 'Oct-21': [nan, -15.0, nan, -20.0]}
```

Test data:

df1

```
{'column1': ['CT', 'CT', 'NBB', 'NBB', 'CT', 'CT', 'NBB', 'NBB', 'HHH', 'HHH', 'TP1', 'TP1', 'TPR', 'TPR', 'PP1', 'PP1', 'PP1', 'PP1'], 'column2': ['POUPOU', 'POUPOU', 'PRPRP', 'PRPRP', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STEVT', 'STEVT', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SHW', 'SHW', 'JV', 'JV'], 'column3': ['V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV'], 'column4': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'column5': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'column6': ['BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'VVV', 'VVV', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CHCH', 'CHCH'], 'column7': ['Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21'], 'Feb-21': [11655, 0, 0, 0, 121117, 0, 14948, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1838, 0, 0, 0], 'Mar-21': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -16474.0, -16474.0, 7000.0, 7000.0, -19946.0, -19946.0, 16084.44444444444, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'Apr-21': [104815.0, 104815.0, 17949.0, 17949.0, 96132.0, 96132.0, 0.0, 0.0, -17001.0, -33475.0, -878.0, 6122.0, 8398.0, -11548.0, -5297.073170731703, -5297.073170731703, -282.0, -282.0], 'May-21': [78260.0, 183075.0, 42557.0, 60506.0, -15265.0, 80867.0, -18.0, -18.0, 21084.0, -12391.0, -1831.0, 4291.0, 2862.0, -8686.0, 5261.25, -35.8231707317027, -369.0, -651.0], 'Jun-21': [-52480.0, 130595.0, -13258.0, 47248.0, -35577.0, 45290.0, 2434.0, 2416.0, 31147.0, 18756.0, -4310.0, -19.0, -4750.0, -13436.0, -92.0, -127.8231707317027, -280.0, -931.0], 'Jul-21': [-174544.0, -43949.0, -38127.0, 9121.0, -124986.0, -79696.0, -9707.0, -7291.0, 13577.0, 32333.0, 0.0, -19.0, -15746.0, -29182.0, 93.0, -34.8231707317027, -319.0, -1250.0], 'Aug-21': [35498.0, -8451.0, -37094.0, -27973.0, 79021.0, -675.0, -1423.0, -8714.0, 32168.0, 64501.0, 0.0, -19.0, 18702.0, -10480.0, 4347.634146341465, 4312.810975609762, -341.0, -1591.0], 'Sep-21': [44195.0, 35744.0, 2039.0, -25934.0, 70959.0, 70284.0, 2816.0, -5898.0, 38359.0, 102860.0, 0.0, -19.0, 18119.0, 7639.0, 5302.222222222219, 9615.033197831981, 0.0, -1591.0], 'Oct-21': [-13163.0, 22581.0, -4773.0, -30707.0, 205080.0, 275364.0, -709.0, -6607.0, -1397.0, 101463.0, 0.0, -19.0, 0.0, 7639.0, -34.0, 9581.033197831981, 0.0, -1591.0]}
```

df2 (expected output) ,

```
{'column1': ['CT', 'CT', 'NBB', 'NBB', 'CT', 'CT', 'NBB', 'NBB', 'HHH', 'HHH', 'TP1', 'TP1', 'TPR', 'TPR', 'PP1', 'PP1', 'PP1', 'PP1'], 'column2': ['POUPOU', 'POUPOU', 'PRPRP', 'PRPRP', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STDD', 'STEVT', 'STEVT', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SYSYS', 'SHW', 'SHW', 'JV', 'JV'], 'column3': ['V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV', 'V', 'CV'], 'column4': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'column5': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'column6': ['BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'VVV', 'VVV', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CHCH', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CHCH', 'CHCH'], 'column7': ['Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-21', 'Mar-21', 'Mar-21'], 'Feb-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Mar-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -16474.0, nan, nan, nan, -19946.0, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Apr-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -17001.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, -11548.0, nan, -5297.073170731703, nan, -282.0], 'May-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -18.0, nan, -12391.0, nan, nan, nan, -8686.0, nan, -35.8231707317027, -369.0, nan], 'Jun-21': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, -4750.0, nan, -92.0, nan, -280.0, nan], 'Jul-21': [nan, -43949.0, nan, nan, nan, -79696.0, nan, -7291.0, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, -15746.0, nan, nan, -34.8231707317027, -319.0, nan], 'Aug-21': [nan, -8451.0, nan, -27973.0, nan, -675.0, -1423.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, nan, -10480.0, nan, nan, -341.0, nan], 'Sep-21': [nan, nan, nan, -25934.0, nan, nan, nan, -5898.0, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -1591.0], 'Oct-21': [nan, nan, -4773.0, nan, nan, nan, -709.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, -19.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -1591.0]}
```

Note: I have implemented my code on the basis of the Test data provided. The sample data is merely to focus on the columns that are supposed to be manipulated.

Comment: Seems like the space is less for posting df2. I shall post it in the following comments.

Comment: You should post the code that allowed you to reach step 3.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I have updated the question with the code. I tried implementing till Step4.2 for the Test data but couldn't get 100% correct expected output. I hope the code helps and an elaborate explanation helps. Please let me know should you have any questions.

Comment: There is a typo in the df1 for july-21.. the first value in images is 30 while in dataset you provide its -30.

Comment: This has already been answered before many times. Treating the blanks in your examples above as `None` or `numpy.nan` in pandas, this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997. Suggest you take down your bounty so it can be marked as such.

Comment: @FrançoisLeblanc - the comparison from right to left and not up to down. If you think this is doable from your side, you're most welcome to take the bounty :)

Comment: Also I don't have the liberty to manipulate the data by using the column headers because month-year header column can anything from Jan-xx to Dec-xx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

For each step, I group on `column1`, then set `column4` as index and work on the transpose matrix with your criteria. Note that I've extrapoled a bit on your criteria to match your attended results (I hope it is correct but you will have to check that).

Note also that I have kept each step separate to make it easier to read. But it would be more efficient to make the grouping/indexing/transposing in one shot and work on your algorithm from there.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)


df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {'column1': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'CDF', 'CDF'], 'column4': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Feb-21': [0, 10, 0, 0], 'Mar-21': [0, 0, 70, 70], 'Apr-21': [-10, -10, -8, 60], 'May-21': [-30, -60, -10, 40], 'Jun-21': [-20, 9, -40, -20], 'Jul-21': [30, -10, 0, -20], 'Aug-21': [-30, -20, 0, -20], 'Sep-21': [0, -15, 0, -20], 'Oct-21': [0, -15, 0, -20]}
        )

print(df1)
print('-'*50)

df = df1.copy()

#step1 :
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].where(df.iloc[:, 2:] < 0, np.nan)


print(df)
print('-'*50)

#step2 :
def step2(df):
    df = df.set_index("column4").T
    ix = df[(df.A<=0) & (df.B.isnull())].index
    df.loc[ix, "A"] = np.nan
    return df.T
df = df.groupby('column1').apply(step2)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
print(df)
print('-'*50)


#step3 :
def step3(df):
    df = df.set_index("column4").T
    ix = df[(df.A.isnull()) & (df.B>=0)].index
    df.loc[ix, "B"] = df.loc[ix, "A"]
    return df.T
df = df.groupby('column1').apply(step3)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
print(df)
print('-'*50)

#step4 :
def step4(df):
    df = df.set_index("column4").T
    a_pos = df.columns.get_loc('A')
    b_pos = df.columns.get_loc('B')
    #step 4.1
    ix = df[(df.A<0) & (df.B<0)].index
    if len(ix):
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        left_pos = ix-1
        condition_left = df.iloc[left_pos].notnull().any(axis=1)
        ix = condition_left[condition_left].index
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        df.iloc[ix+1, b_pos] = np.nan
    
    #step 4.2
    ix = df[(df.A<0) & (df.B<0)].index
    if len(ix):
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        left_pos = ix-1
        condition_left = df.iloc[left_pos].isnull().all(axis=1)    
        ix = condition_left[condition_left].index
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        df.iloc[ix+1, a_pos] = np.nan
    
    #step 4.1 (again)
    ix = df[(df.A<0) & (df.B<0)].index
    if len(ix):
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        left_pos = ix-1
        condition_left = df.iloc[left_pos].notnull().any(axis=1)
        ix = condition_left[condition_left].index
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        df.iloc[ix+1, b_pos] = np.nan
        
    return df.T

df = df.groupby('column1').apply(step4)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
print(df)
print('-'*50)
```

**EDIT**

I'll assume here (based on your previous comment) that your dataframe will always be composed of A/B rows in alternance (and that the order in the dataframe is valid). We will then need to compute an artificial index to indentify each pair of rows.

Note that I used a `fillna` on your columns (mainly column5) as it is good practice with the `groupby` commands. Due to multiple levels of columns, I'm not sure it will have an impact anyway...

Boolean indexing begins to be tricky when managing multiple levels of columns. You will see I will compute each "column" to a numpy.array (using the `.values` method). Somehow, pandas won't perform the boolean match on multiple columns, I'm not exactly sure why.

So this goes :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(  ...  )

#Compute the unique index for each pair of rows
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
ix = df.index
ix = ix[ix%2==0]
df.loc[ix, 'index'] = df.shift(-1).loc[ix, 'index']

#step1 :
cols = [x for x in df.columns.tolist() if not x.startswith('column') and x != "index"]
df[cols] = df[cols].where(df[cols] < 0, np.nan)


cols_index = ["column4", "column1", "column2", "column3", "column5", "column6", "column7"]
df[cols_index] = df[cols_index].fillna(-1)

#step2 :
def step2(df):
    df = df.set_index(cols_index).drop('index', axis=1).T
    ix = df[
            (df.A<=0).values
            & df.B.isnull().values
         ].index
    df.loc[ix, "A"] = np.nan
    return df.T
df = df.groupby('index').apply(step2)
print(df)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
print(df)
print('-'*50)


#step3 :
def step3(df):
    df = df.set_index(cols_index).drop('index', axis=1).T
    ix = df[
            df.A.isnull().values 
            & (df.B>=0).values
            ].index
    df.loc[ix, "B"] = df.loc[ix, "A"]
    return df.T
df = df.groupby('index').apply(step3)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
print(df)
print('-'*50)

#step4 :
def step4(df):
    df = df.set_index(cols_index).drop('index', axis=1).T
    a_pos = df.columns.get_loc('A')
    b_pos = df.columns.get_loc('B')
    
    #step 4.1
    ix = df[
            (df.A<0).values
            & (df.B<0).values
            ].index
    if len(ix):
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        left_pos = ix-1
        condition_left = df.iloc[left_pos].notnull().any(axis=1)
        ix = condition_left[condition_left].index
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        df.iloc[ix+1, b_pos] = np.nan
    
    #step 4.2
    ix = df[
            (df.A<0).values
            & (df.B<0).values
            ].index
    if len(ix):
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        left_pos = ix-1
        condition_left = df.iloc[left_pos].isnull().all(axis=1)    
        ix = condition_left[condition_left].index
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        df.iloc[ix+1, a_pos] = np.nan
    
    #step 4.1 (again)
    ix = df[
            (df.A<0).values
            & (df.B<0).values
            ].index
    if len(ix):
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        left_pos = ix-1
        condition_left = df.iloc[left_pos].notnull().any(axis=1)
        ix = condition_left[condition_left].index
        ix = df.index.get_indexer(ix)
        df.iloc[ix+1, b_pos] = np.nan
        
    return df.T

df = df.groupby('index').apply(step4)
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
print(df)
print('-'*50)
```

And if you want to restore your column5 :

```
df[cols_index] = df[cols_index].replace(-1, np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks, did you try running your algorithm using the test data? If so, may I know what would I need to change in your current code?

Comment: So, I did try to run your code with the Test data and got the following error in step2, 

`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: Would you happen to have any insights on how to deal with this problem? or if anything is unclear please let me know because I feel this is really close to the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that your other sample had a different structure. This exception is raised because of this (in fact, it's because column1 can be duplicated more than once). To help you, I will need to know more about the indexing of your dataframe : can you indentify an unique couple using a combination of column1 to column 7 ? Or can we assume that your dataset will always be constructed with rows in alternance ?

Comment: No problem. 
First question: I don't think we have any combinations that we may use them uniquely. 
Second question: Not sure what you mean exactly. The structure of the data, that I am working with, is of the same structure, that I can say for sure.

Comment: *The structure of the Test data..
(For some reason I can't edit my comment)

Comment: Have edited my answer. Hope this will match your real dataset (my code should make my previous comment more concrete)

Comment: Now, I understand what you mean. The assumption is correct, they are always in alternate. Thanks so much for your efforts. Since the bounty is expiring soon and I really want to give you the bounty rep, hence I am giving it to you, however, I might or might not (hopefully not) need your help in this question should there be discrepancy in near future.

Comment: Anytime ! Though if that's because my explanations are not clear enough, feal free to share the problematic parts with me ;-)